# How to get a new default.plymouth in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: boot, plymouth

I know this is unusual... I accidentally damaged the `default.plymouth` file, which is located at `/usr/share/plymouth/themes`, because of desperate pursue of changing my boot screen into a macOS boot screen display. As a result, my boot screen has no more boot screen display. When it starts, it's all blank; when shuts down, it shows codes.

Please, can anyone help me with this... I just want to have an aesthetic boot screen.

Comment: try to reinstall the package `sudo apt install --reinstall plymouth`

Comment: I already tried that... the default.plymouth is still missing.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/plymouth

Answer (score 0):

In this post there is the contents of the default.plymouth file. Try manually creating it in the correct dir: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth

I have a Mac boot screen so if you need help switching to that just ask.